# \ifinner not working in \@footnotetext

Tags: footnotes, tex-core

I was trying to improve an old answer and ran into a problem.  `\ifinner` is telling me I am in outer mode inside a `\parbox`.  It usually works, but not in this case (`\@footnotetext`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\parboxins}

\newcommand{\copyinserts}{\insert\footins{\unvbox\parboxins}}

\newcommand{\global@insert}[2]% #1=box number, #2=vertical list
{\bgroup
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\box#1
  \global\setbox#1=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa #2}
\egroup}
%{\global\setbox#1=\vbox{\unvbox#1 #2}}

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\ifinner INNER \global@insert\parboxins
 \else OUTER \insert\footins
 \fi{%    
 \reset@font\footnotesize
 \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
 \splittopskip\footnotesep
 \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
 \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
 \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
 \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
 }%
 \color@begingroup
 \@makefntext{%
 \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
 \color@endgroup}}%

%\newcommand{\globalinserts}{\let\@footnotetext=\global@footnotetext}% doesn't work
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\ifinner INNER\else OUTER\fi

\parbox{\textwidth}{\ifinner INNER\else OUTER\fi}

normal\footnote{normal}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\parbox[t]{1in}{parbox\footnote{parbox - \blindtext}}%
\usebox{\parboxins}\copyinserts
\item test
\end{enumerate}

check counter\footnote{after}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `ifinner` in a parbox is telling you that you are in inner vertical mode (as you are inside a box so no page breaking)

The second `ifinner` in a parbox is telling you that you are in outer horizontal mode as you are not in an hbox, so there is linebreaking

The example can be simplifed to

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\ifinner INNER\else OUTER\fi

\parbox{\textwidth}{\ifinner INNER\else OUTER\fi}

\parbox{\textwidth}{x\ifinner INNER\else OUTER\fi}



\end{document}
```

Comment: So \ifinner has to be the first thing in the \parbox to work. Sigh!

Comment: @JohnKormylo well in vmode so after a blank line before the second para would also work but basically ifinner almost never tells you anything you want to know